# Easygui input error

Tags: python, input, easygui

The following code gives me an error.

```
import easygui
result = easygui.enterbox(message="Enter your name", title="Name query", argDefaultText="Ian Ozsvald")
```

This is the error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Volumes/CHROME
>   USB/STORAGE/TKinker GUI/easygui inputbox.py", line 2, in 
>       result = easygui.enterbox(message="Enter your name", title="Name query", argDefaultText="Ian Ozsvald") TypeError: enterbox() got an
>   unexpected keyword argument 'message'

I'm running Python 2.5 on OS X Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`easygui.enterbox` has no argument `message`, nor `argDefaultText`.

What you want is:

```
import easygui
result = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter your name', title='Name query', default='Ian Ozsvald')
```

The signature of the `enterbox` function can be found here:

http://easygui.sourceforge.net/download/version0.95/pydoc/easygui.html#-enterbox

alternate link
http://www.ferg.org/easygui/easygui.html#-enterbox